Problem with @click.native when migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3
I have a dynamic component, and the click event only works with @click.native. I tried following the documentation, but it didn't work. The only way I managed to get it to work is by adding a wrapper around the component, but that ends up modifying the style of the icons, or by using @click.native, which is deprecated
I'm using vue/compat and the Icons are svg
<template>
  <component
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :is="MyIcons[iconName]"
    @click.native="(event: Event) => emit('click', event)"
  />
</template>

I tried add a wrapper but it change icons style also I tried what the docs suggests https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-on-native-modifier-removed
the solution for my problem

const element = ref<HTMLDivElement>();
useEventListener(element, "click", (e) => {
  emit("click");
});

<template>
  <component
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :is="MyIcons[iconName]"
    ref="element"
  />
</template>


Can you provide a minimal reproduction ? The wrapper component option seems to be the most straightforward option. Regarding the styling it can always be adjusted. Are you using Vite for the build ? If so you can use vite-svg-loader to load svgs as components.

thanks GeorgesA  I find a way to solve my problem using https://vueuse.org/core/useEventListener/

Nice ! Would you be able to share your solution for others to benefit from it ?

sure, sorry for the late reply
